# How do I only output an IPv4 address from my PC when a BOT is running

Tags: c#, web-crawler, bots, ipv6, ipv4

I am trying to obtain some data from a site that I need and I am trying to follow the rules in this article (half way down "A message for the other side") > http://blog.strictly-software.com/2010/04/banning-bad-bots-with-mod-rewrite.html by not over-crawling it, changing user-agents and referers, and I was using proxies until they got blocked but I have 2 problems.

The BOT is a synchronous process with timeouts to stop any hammering of the site and I only crawl a little but I have an issue that because my ISP is BT they use IPv6 addresses and so in the remote servers log file they obviously see my IPv6 fixed address a lot and can ban it if they want to easily.

If I just go to the URL http://icanhazip.com it outputs 2a00:23d8:1d9b:bd01:4ae:d9b1:7162:ff79.

If I got to a special URL that forces IPv4 https://ipv4.lafibre.info/ip.php it outputs 81.154.127.227. This changes a lot with BT, almost every couple of days, whilst the IPv6 address stays the same the IPv4 address changes a lot and bounces all around my local area if doing a geo-ip location lookup.

The problem is obviously that the site I am crawling is blocking my IPv6 address as it must be appearing in their log files a lot.

So the question is How do I force my BOT to ONLY output an IPv4 address so that the remote server sees that and not the permanent IPv6 one?

Also when trying to parse an IPAddress, the IPAddress.Parse function does not work with IPv6 addresses e.g

```
IPAddress IP = null; // return type from the function that gets the IP address

// get response of IP address page
StreamReader ResponseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

if (ipv6)
{
    IP = ResponseStream.ReadToEnd(); // what can I put around this to return an IPAddress type, or should I just return a string?
}
else
{
    IP = IPAddress.Parse(ResponseStream.ReadToEnd()); // this works fine
}
```

So is there a different IPAddress type for IPv6 addresses in C#, or a different method for parsing IPv6 addresses, and what is it?

OR should I just be returning strings from pages returning IPv6 addresses instead?

Comment: The IP address is in the packet header, and IPv6 packets can only have IPv6 addresses. You cannot put an IPv4 address in an IPv6 packet header. Also, that address is needed in order for you to get replies.

Comment: But the IPv4 address must be in some header as its shown when I go to geo location sites or that URL I said > https://ipv4.lafibre.info/ip.php so what header is that site picking up for it to show my IPv4 address and why does my ISP need to broadcast both formats, can I not pick or force one? If I had a VPN whilst my BOT was running and my code was switched not to tamper with headers at all, would that solve the issue of- the remote site picking up my IPv6 address, would it just see the VPNS address whatever it was, same with proxies? They were working but last crawl showed 403 status codes.

Comment: Also would my ISP BT be able to turn on in their data centre and here at home the ability to only output the IPv4 address and not the IPv6? I had another hosting company that thought its IP was whitelisted on another site but after ages of them thinking it was broken I did a simple test to see what status code came back 403, then used that URL to see what format it was in - IPv6, the hosting company changed the format so it would only output IPv4 to other sites. Also the question of parsing IPv6 addresses with IPAddress.Parse - is there an equivalent for IPv6 addresses or a different type?

Comment: Most OSes and applications (browsers) will default to IPv6 when you have both. What you really need to do is follow the rules for crawling. You are simply doing it too often, or you are ignoring the robots.txt file on sites. There are companies that do this all the time and not get blocked because they follow the rules and wishes of the site owners.

Comment: As I said in the post with the link, I am following the Karmic rules of scraping, I've been on both ends having to block repeated bandwidth wasters and hammering BOTS that one tweet with a link can take a site down due to a twitter rush > http://blog.strictly-software.com/2015/05/twitter-rush-rush-just-gets-bigger-and.html and I put delays in between crawls, cache pages rather than re-get them, follow robots.txt, and its just automating what millions of people do manually each day on that site anyway, go from page to page to get the info they need for the day.

Comment: I just want to know though if I used a VPN without any code for proxies etc in my BOT would that work by constantly changing location of my computer around the world and sending different IP addresses and I am on Win 8.1r and it is only since moving to BT that IPv6 has been an issue especially getting into servers past firewalls or SFTP that still require IPv4 addresses. So is there any way of forcing the OS to use IPv4 or IPv6 and what actual Response headers do the two turn up in if both are being sent out. Could I not change X-Forwarded-For or something?